# Could not start printer

Tags: printing

When I am trying to print PDF document in Libra office I get this error message:

> Could not start printer. Please check your printer configuration.

My printer is brother DCP-350C, i downloaded drive from site, installed it, error continue, i started to follow random tutorials about adding generic drives changing ports and such, nothing, error persists, Document print status shows **cancelled** despite me not cancelling it, it doesn't give me any error details why this happens.

I use mint 19.3

Comment: What is "Libra office"? Do you mean LibreOffice? Can you print text documents from LibreOffice and other applications (e.g. your browser)?

Comment: What was this driver you installed?  Was it a PPD?  Did you install it by simply copying the PPD to /usr/share/ppd or did you do something in the CUPS browser page?

Comment: I installed dcp350ccupswrapper-1.0.1-1.i386.deb. then clicked it and it said all dependencies have been satisfied and installation is finished, I downloaded it from brother site. I can't print from any application. or any file, error stays same.. I forgot to add, printer is recognized in "printers" and appears, with all settings and so on, It just doesn't print anything and all prints i sent appear as canceled.

Comment: Update, On win7 old laptop printer works with out issues, I wonder if i can run vm on linux and print through vm? I would love if someone would shine light if they had experience with such or tell me is it worth it or not, my pc is beefy and it's capable of ruining variety of vm's at same time.

Comment: The CUPS Admin interface at `http://localhost:631/admin` will help you.

Comment: it says i have no privileges to access this settings, i also noticed same error appears when printer is unpluged from pc.

Comment: update, i still haven't figured how to use my printer through linux, but i found tutorial how to enable usb ports in virtualbox, i instaled windows 7 and now i can print through it, so i can now use my printer through vm only,

Comment: another update, i found out printer doesn't work on vm with win10 on it, it works on win7 only.

Comment: Update nr 4, i think i might pinpoint why printer have issues, it seems to require specific usb 2.0 settings in vm, while giving same error it's giving on main system when i set ports to 3.0 so it might be some usb buss problem? I am bad at this i will look it up.